# How to pass the variable from jFrame to another jFrame?

Tags: java

**jFrame1**

```
      Connect con=new Connect(); // connection of db
      int row=jTable1.getSelectedRow(); ()
      String table_click=(JTableCustomer.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
      String query="select * from addcustomer where Customerid='"+table_click+"'";
      rs=con.getQuery(query);
      if(rs.next()){
          String add1=rs.getString("Customerid");
          jtxtCustomerId1.setText(add1);  //this is right

          // I want to pass add2 for another jFrame form

          String add2=rs.getString("Fullname");
          Invoice x=new Invoice();
          x.setcustomer(add2);

}
```

**At Invoice**

```
  public void setcustomer (String Name){
        jtxtCustomer.setText(Name);
  }
```

Comment: Anyone can me help ?

Comment: That's not entirely wrong, but now you have the problem, that Invoice x is a local variable and soon be lost, because outside of the scope it isn't visible, except you have access to the second JFrame, so that you can add x to that JFrame. Or is Invoice itself that other JFrame? Then you should declare it outside of the method.

Comment: thank you @user unknown but it not working

Answer (score 0):

You can let 2 jframes know about each other. For example:

```
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
frame1.setFrame2(frame2); // inside frame1, there is a variable frame2
```

Once two objects have references to each other, they can access data from each other.